# вывод данных Frontend в компоненте Joomla 3.5

Tags: php, joomla, frontend

Люди, ну, хоть подскажите где можно попросить помощи... или почитать по теме..

Уважаемые разработчики, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как лучше вывести выборку данных из таблицы SQL cms Joomla 3.5 в определенный div соответствующего материала? Административная часть компонента уже готова, а с таким выводом пользовательской части пока не могу разобраться. Подробности: есть общая таблица SQL со списком услуг, в которой одно из полей соответствуют метке материала. Нужно в определенный div (servicelist) материала вывести название услуги и цену (столбцы item и price таблицы SQL), содержащую только те записи, метка которых (section) равна метке материала. Вывод нужен в табличной форме с чекбоксом в последнем столбце. Код Модели:
class PricelistModelPricelist extends JModelList {

```
protected function getListQuery() {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(TRUE);

    //SELECT ....
    $query->select('`item`,`price`,`section`');
    //FROM
    $query->from('#__pricelist');
    //WHERE
    $query->where('`published` = 1,');
    //ORDER BY
    $query->order('`item` ASC');
    return $query;      
}
```

Код Вида:
class PricelistViewPricelist extends JViewLegacy {

```
    protected $items;

    function display($tpl = null) {
        $this->items = $this->get('Items');

        parent::display($tpl);
    }

}
```

А вод с кодом шаблона views...\tmpl\default.php - разобраться не могу уже:

```html
<?php if(!empty($this->items) && is_array($this->items)) :?>
<?php foreach($this->items as $item) :?>
<div class="pricelist1">

</div>

<?php endforeach;?>


<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте:

```
<?php if(!empty($this->items) && is_array($this->items)) { ?>
  <?php foreach($this->items as $item) { ?>
    <div class="pricelist1">

    </div>
  <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @Iван Цуркан Спасибо! На консоли ошибок нет, но и вывод не работает. Не могу понять возможные причины :( :в исходном коде страницы даже выборка не отражается